# Is there a way to see the number of views since last edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, views

Is there a way to see the number of users who viewed a question since it was last edited?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. This is because SE does not track views beyond a counter.

So at any one time, you only know the total views. There is no information about *when* the views came or how they are distributed as a function of time.

Votes, on the other hand, *are* tracked with time-stamps. So it's easy to determine how many votes came before or after an edit.

You can get a day-to-day break down of voting histories (among other things) from the question timeline.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/timeline
(Change the number to whatever question id you want.)

---

I'm not sure what purpose you have for seeing a history of *views*. But for higher profile questions, votes correlate very well with views.

So if you're just looking to make cool-looking graphs like this, votes is good enough.

[image]

Comment: Worth to mention the timeline page and how to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to see the number of views since the last edit.